# "Initializer element is not constant" - but it clearly is

Tags: c, macros, avr, avr-gcc

I know what the message means, but not why it happened.

```
main.c:26:2: error: initializer element is not constant
  rgb24_xrgb(0xB14835), // brick red
```

My code:

```
typedef uint32_t rgb24_t;

// Color structure
typedef struct {
    uint8_t r;
    uint8_t g;
    uint8_t b;
} xrgb_t;

// Table of colors
const xrgb_t COLORS[] = {
    rgb24_xrgb(0xB14835), // brick red
    rgb24_xrgb(0x4C1661), // indigo
    rgb24_xrgb(0xA3268E), // royal purple
};
```

Here are my macros:

```
#define xrgb(rr, gg, bb) ((xrgb_t) { .r = ((uint8_t)(rr)), .g = ((uint8_t)(gg)), .b = ((uint8_t)(bb)) })
#define rgb24_r(c) ((((rgb24_t) (c)) >> 16) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_g(c) ((((rgb24_t) (c)) >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_b(c) ((((rgb24_t) (c)) >> 0) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_xrgb(c) xrgb(rgb24_r(c), rgb24_g(c), rgb24_b(c))
```

The preprocessor output is here:

```
const xrgb_t COLORS[] = {
    ((xrgb_t) { .r = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xB14835)) >> 16) & 0xFF))), .g = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xB14835)) >> 8) & 0xFF))), .b = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xB14835)) >> 0) & 0xFF))) }),
    ((xrgb_t) { .r = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0x4C1661)) >> 16) & 0xFF))), .g = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0x4C1661)) >> 8) & 0xFF))), .b = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0x4C1661)) >> 0) & 0xFF))) }),
    ((xrgb_t) { .r = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xA3268E)) >> 16) & 0xFF))), .g = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xA3268E)) >> 8) & 0xFF))), .b = ((uint8_t)(((((rgb24_t) (0xA3268E)) >> 0) & 0xFF))) })
};
```

Looks fairly constant to me.

Where is the problem?

Comment: To fix this remove the `((xrgb_t)` and the associated trailing `)`

Comment: certain portions of your code are outside the compiler scope, I.E. they need to execute code and no code execution is allowed when using an initializer

Comment: @user3629249 the arithmetic operations are permitted in constant expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From C11 6.7.9/4  (C99 had similar text):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

From C11 6.6 "Constant expressions":

> More latitude is permitted for constant expressions in initializers. Such a constant
>   expression shall be, or evaluate to, one of the following:
>
> - an arithmetic constant expression,
> - a null pointer constant,
> - an address constant, or
> - an address constant for a complete object type plus or minus an integer constant
>     expression.

A compound literal is none of those bullet points, so it is not permitted in an initializer.

I don't see any rationale as to *why* it is not permitted, if the compound literal's initializers are all constant expressions that meet these criteria.

However you can work around this by just using the initializers without the compound literal:

```
const xrgb_t COLORS[] = {
    { .r = ........... , .g = ............., .b = ........ },
    { .r = .......  // etc.
};
```

This should be easy to do in your existing code by renaming your  macro to just give the `{ }` part, and then have another macro with the original name that does `(const xrgb_t) rgb24_xrgb(X)` to make the compound literal, or whatever.

NB. Making the compound literal `const` lets the compiler store it in read-only area.

Comment: You are right, that's indeed the problem and I ended up with `blah` and `blahc` versions of the macro, `blahc` being without the cast. It's really a weird restriction though, and leads to messier code...

Comment: I'm guessing it's somehow connected to the fact that a compound literal is a modifiable lvalue, e.g. `(int){1} = 2;` is valid.

Comment: @Leushenko This is valid? Somehow I fail to see how you could assign value to a literal - what will it produce? NOP?

Comment: @MightyPork compound literals either have static or automatic storage duration (depending on where declared), but they are not `const` unless you explicitly make them const. The design mistake of string literals was not repeated.  They behave like variables. Hence my suggestion to use `const` on them as much as possible, especially if you're in embedded where you don't want to waste the non-const data area

Comment: Using `const` also allows the compiler to collapse identical literals (which it can't for non-const in case you write them).

Comment: @MattMcNabb but declaring them const won't work if the values are somehow computed, no? Only with constant values in the struct

Comment: @MightyPork arithmetic (which includes bitwise operators) still counts as constant expression, if the operands are constant

Comment: Also, any time you can declare a non-const object (including compound literals) you can also add `const` to it, that just means that your code is not allowed to write the object thereafter. For example `const int x = argc;`

Comment: yeah got it, so expressions in `xrgb()` are fine, but I can't modify the color components after it's in a const variable.

Answer (score -2):

The following works
compiles cleanly
it is still a lot messier that it needs to be:

```
// Color structure
struct xrgb_t
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};


#define xrgb(rr, gg, bb) ((struct xrgb_t) { .r = ((unsigned char)(rr)), .g = ((unsigned char)(gg)), .b = ((unsigned char)(bb)) })
#define rgb24_r(c) ((((unsigned char) (c)) >> 16) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_g(c) ((((unsigned char) (c)) >> 8) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_b(c) ((((unsigned char) (c)) >> 0) & 0xFF)
#define rgb24_xrgb(c) xrgb(rgb24_r(c), rgb24_g(c), rgb24_b(c))


// Table of colors
const struct xrgb_t COLORS[] =
{
    rgb24_xrgb(0xB14835), // brick red
    rgb24_xrgb(0x4C1661), // indigo
    rgb24_xrgb(0xA3268E), // royal purple
};
```

my preferred method would be:

```
struct xrgb_t
{
    unsigned char r;
    unsigned char g;
    unsigned char b;
};

#define set_xrgb(y)  {((y)>>16)&0xFF}, {((y)>>8)&0xFF}, {((y)&0xFF)}
// Table of colors
const struct xrgb_t COLORS[] =
{
    set_xrgb(0xB14835), // brick red
    set_xrgb(0x4C1661), // indigo
    set_xrgb(0xA3268E)  // royal purple
};
```

Comment: `((unsigned char)(c)) >> 16` is zero, so surely this is not what OP intended

Comment: Also this is invalid in Standard C, when you say "it compiles" perhaps you are using a compiler extension which allows non-constant expressions in initializers.

Comment: You've done quite a lot edits to the code, so even if it works, I can't use it. It's for AVR, compiled with avr-gcc. Your "preferred method" is closer to my current solution. Also, `rgb24_t` is typedef alias of `uint32_t`, so your assumption of `uchar` is not even close, and  it would not work.